# how to create WCF Callback c#

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

I'm trying to crease a wcf service that will accept an interface and activates it when other wcf function will be called by clients.
Wcf Service Interface:

```
  [ServiceContract]
        public interface IAction
        {
            [OperationContract]
            void OnIndexChanged(int index);
        }

        // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IService1
        {

            [OperationContract]
            void Add(int iCount);

            [OperationContract]
            void Subtract(int iCount);

            [OperationContract]
            void Subscribe(IAction action);
            // TODO: Add your service operations here
        }
```

WCF Service Implementation:

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        static int index = 0;
        static IAction act = null;

        public void Add(int iCount)
        {
            index += iCount;
            act?.OnIndexChanged(index);
        }

        public void Subscribe(IAction action)
        {
            act = action;
        }

        public void Subtract(int iCount)
        {
            index -= iCount;
            act?.OnIndexChanged(index);
        }
    }
```

client's :

```
 public class TestAction : IAction
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }

        public void Run()
        {
            Index = 0;

            WCF.IService1 service = new WCF.Service1Client();
            try
            {
                service.Subscribe(this);
                service.Add(3);
                service.Subtract(2);
                service.Add(1);
            }
           catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        public void OnIndexChanged(int index)
        {
            Index = index;
            Console.WriteLine("On_Changed_Index is - > " + index);
        }
    }
```

Main :

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TestAction ts = new TestAction();
            ts.Run();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Yet it doesn't work. It says that there is a type serialize exception as follows:

```
 There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:action. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Tester.TestAction' with data contract name 'TestAction:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Tester' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Does anyone knows why is that? I do not want to give a specific name because each client has a different Implemantation in a different project, so I can't specify the type to the type at the TestAction Class.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. Basically when WCF runtime receives request, depending upon Action present in SOAP (method you invoked from client), using reflection it creates an instance of service and will invoke that Action on that instance. Also during the process it going to pass parameters to that action by deserializing parameters sent in SOAP packet as per data contract. Having said that, this implies that all this is happening in different app domain (in fact process) and usual OOP concepts live overload, override won't work out as you expecting. In your example, service does not know anything about `TestAction` as you using SOAP to communicate with some objects in another process/machine altogether. Make sense ?

Comment: Yeah I see, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve the callback through events but WCF has a built in method to support this feature.

Since **IAction** is your callback method,no need to decorate with Service contract.

```
public interface IAction
    {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void OnIndexChanged(int index);
    }
```

So inform the contract that **IService1** that you have a callback associated.

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IAction))]
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

```
    [OperationContract]
    void Add(int iCount);

    [OperationContract]
    void Subtract(int iCount);

    }
```

Now you can decide when to call your callback method.

```
public void Add(int iCount)
        {
       index += iCount;                
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IAction>().OnIndexChanged(index);
        }
```

Similarly for subtract method also.

Now if you want to call the callback you need to just call the callback's interface method by implementing in your main class's method.

```
 [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]


 class MyClass:FullNameSpace.IAction 
    {
       public void MainMethod()
       {
       InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
         mynamespace.Service1 client = new
          //your add and subtract method can be accessed by client.
       }
        public void OnIndexChanged(int index)
        {
           string result= = index.ToString() ;      
        }
    }
```